# php, how to treat arrays with floats inside?

Tags: php, arrays, floating-point

example:

the following is correct?

```
$var = floatval($arr[2]) ;
```

"You cannot use floatval() on arrays..." maybe that's an old directive or how to edit...?

Comment: `$arr = explode(";",$line) ;` is a parsing from a csv file...

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($arr);`

Comment: For parsing CSV, you should use `fgetcsv`. (Not that this has anything to do with this question.)

Comment: "You cannot use floatval() on arrays..." is not an output error, i read it on the manual...but i don't know if is old or not...i asked 'cause the whole script has a strange behaviour with the final result when add a percentage increase

Comment: Well, arrays naturally won't cast to any meaningful float value, hence the warning in the manual. If the above is not giving an error, this question is baseless.

Comment: "you cannot..." doesn't seem a warning only... maybe you mean that is baseless that "warning" :-) but you're not answering to my question: so, there is a specific and correct way to treat arrays when they contain floats? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That quote from the manual (which BTW doesn't seem to exist in the current manual anymore) only means that you can't use `floatval` on values that *are* arrays, i.e.:

```
$foo = array();
$bar = floatval($foo);
```

Which, BTW, is not entirely correct, since it would produce either `1.0` or `0.0`, depending on whether the array was *empty* or not.* It just doesn't make much sense. If you access a scalar value inside an array, that's not using "`floatval` on an array". I.e., this works perfectly fine:

```
$foo = array("42.1231");
$bar = floatval($foo[0]);
```

That's using the scalar value in `$foo[0]`, whether that's in an array or not is irrelevant.

---

* The manual now clearly [says](http://www.php.net/floatval) `Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.` Maybe this behavior has changed?

Answer (score -2):

you will need to traverse the array and perform the operation on each element:

```
foreach($arr as $id=>$elem){
  $arr[$id]=floatval($elem);
}
```

Comment: There's no fundamental difference between it and `floatval($arr[2])`.